# Как выровнять текст по оси Y?

Tags: html, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Как в css опустить текст с ссылкой вниз. Заранее спасибо!

```css
body {
  background: #2F2F2F;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  width: 1320px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.div {
  border: 1px;
  background: Black;
  height: 70px;
}

.c {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 400px;
  text-decoration-color: Orange;
  color: White;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="div">
    <a class="c" href="">Contracts</a> // это подвинуть надо вниз
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Я как не пытался сдвинуть не получилось

Comment: если без flex, то можно .div сделать position: relative, а .c сделать position: absolute; bottom: 0

Comment: что бы .с стал на свое место надо у див.див задатъ позишен какой нибудъ
проще всего сразу добавитъ
п1озишен аюсолют
п1озишен релатив
п1озишен фиксед
и удаляя 1 по одному, ишешь какое соотношение тегов тебе подойдет
что то типа маргинботтом 0
или маргинтоп 90процентов
там много вариантов
например вставить пустой блок на 90 процентов перед ссылкой и он ее подвинет вниз если у тебя див.див класс флекс или табле

Answer (score 0):

Изучите тему flex box.

```
.div {
    border: 1px;
    background: Black;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: если надо прижать вниз, то точно не через center

Comment: Исправил свой ответ.  Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Этот normalize используется в этом компоненте для нормализации стилей.  */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}  

html, body {  
  background: #2F2F2F;
  height: 100%; 
}

header { 
 background: Black;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  padding: 15px;
}
.item {  
    display: flex; 
    align-items: flex-end;
    border: 1px;
    min-height: 70px;
}
.link {  
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration-color: Orange;
    color: White;
    font-family: Arial; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>RekrutStandOff</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <div class='wrapper'> 
           <div class="item">
              <a class="link" href="/">Contracts</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я тебя правильно понял и ты хочешь поставить ссылку внизу по центру то добавляешь к блоку див display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: flex-end; . Не понял зачем тебе лишний див на всю ширину в хедере, но ладно

```css
 body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
 }
 header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border: 1px;
  background: Black;
  height: 70px;
}

.c {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration-color: Orange;
  color: White;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="div">
    <a class="c" href="">Contracts</a>
  </div>
</header>
```